# How to change the shortcut keys used in vi editor?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vi, key-bindings

The vi editor uses some shortcut keys to move the cursor. 
How can I customize those [key bindings](https://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/vi.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a tutorial to change the keymaping for [VIM](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29), but i don't recommend this, since vim is supposed to be a fast text editor.